# JMeter Worker YAML

Tags: jmeter, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

I had a question about the properties within the JMeter Worker YAML file. Currently we are using Azure node with the below spec:

[B8ms spec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9EdW.png)

CPU | RAM | Data Disks | Max IOPS | Temp Storage

The properties for the JMeter worker are the following:

```
# JMeter Worker Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: jmeter-workers
  namespace: execution
  labels:
    jmeter_mode: slave
spec:
  replicas: 1 
  serviceName: jmeter-workers-svc
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      jmeter_mode: slave
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        jmeter_mode: slave
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: jmslave
        image: crpplshduks.azurecr.io/devops-tools/jmeterworker:5.4.3.4
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1099
        - containerPort: 50000
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 2
            memory: 2G
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
      nodeSelector:
        type: hp
```

My question was specifically about the values used for these properties:

```
        cpu: 2
        memory: 2G
```

Currently when running tests with 1000-2000 users the node CPU isn't going above 20%. If I removed these properties or left them blank, would that allow the workers to use the full resources available on the node machines? What is the best practice?

From current tests, with these properties, a JMeter worker can only handle 25-30 concurrent users before we start seeing response times being skewed in Grafana. Grafana is reporting 1-2min response times. But when manually going to the application and testing the same pages, lower response times are observed.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/)

> By default, a container has no resource constraints and can use as much of a given resource as the host’s kernel scheduler allows

so if you remove the constraints only underlying [Linux kernel](https://github.com/torvalds/linux) will decide how many CPU ticks and RAM pages will be allocated to the container.

The other story is [JMeter itself](https://jmeter.apache.org/), first of all you need to make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html). Also as of [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5) it allocates to itself [1 GB of JVM heap](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.5/bin/jmeter.bat#L151) so you might want to increase this as well